# Why does my /login page not show up when i run flask application

Tags: python, html, flask

I wanted to make a login page with app route /login The login page does not show up on the page when I enter http://127.0.0.1:5000/login. I created
an html file that is a basic login page. I followed a tutorial and copied the code but it wont show up.

this is my  main file

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["nm"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}</h1>" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here is my login html file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="#" method="post">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="nm" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my base file which works which I used bootstrapping for a navigation bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FINANCEPAL</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown link
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
</body>

</html>
```

I tried looking for the error in the blocks but I cant seem to fix it.

Comment: just a blank page. index.html works and displays the code  but login.html doesn't. I just click the run python file in terminal button is vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `base.html` makes provision for a block called `body`, but the block in your `login.html` is called `content`.

In login.html, change:

```
{% block content %}
```

to:

```
{% block body %}
```